# Custom Spray Formatter for NonEmptyList[A]

Tags: json, scala, spray

I'm trying to write a custom JSON Formatter for my `NonEmptyList[A]`:

```
package net

import spray.json._
import Foo.NonEmptySeq

class NonEmptyCustomFormatter[A](implicit ev: A => JsValue) 
    extends JsonFormat[NonEmptySeq[A]] {
  override def read(json: JsValue): NonEmptySeq[A] = 
    ???

  override def write(xs: NonEmptySeq[A]): JsValue = {
    val values: Seq[JsValue] = Foo.toSeq[A](xs).map(ev(_))
    JsArray( values: _* )
  }
}

object Foo {

    type NonEmptySeq[A] = (A, Seq[A])

    def toSeq[A](neq: NonEmptySeq[A]): Seq[A] = 
        neq._1 +: neq._2

    implicit def stringToJsValue(x: String): JsValue = JsString(x)
}
```

REPL example:

```
scala> import spray.json._
import spray.json._

scala> import net._
import net._

scala> import net.Foo._
import net.Foo._

scala> implicit object NonEmptyStringList extends NonEmptyCustomFormatter[String]
defined object NonEmptyStringList

scala> val xs: NonEmptySeq[String] = ("foo", Nil)
xs: net.Foo.NonEmptySeq[String] = (foo,List())

scala> xs.toJson
res0: spray.json.JsValue = ["foo"]
```

Next, I was about to implement the `read` method, currently defined as `???`.

If I had a non-generic, i.e. `String-specific` formatter, then I could simply pattern match on `JsString`, returning a `deserializationError` if it's not a `JsString`.

However, since a `JsArray` can have 0 or more `JsValue` elements, must I resort to reflection? Basically, I want to define another `(implicit ev2: JsValue => A)` **without** reflection.

How can I do that?

**EDIT**

I changed the `ev2` type signature from `JsValue => Option[A]` to `JsValue => A` - since an exception will be thrown (per spray convention, as I understand) to indicate a deserialization failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to use reflection at all. What you need is an instance of JsonFormat for A and compose your NonEmptySeq format with that. Then you can use `toJson` and `convertTo[A]`

For example:

```
class NonEmptyCustomFormatter[A : JsonFormat] extends JsonFormat[NonEmptySeq[A]] {

  override def read(json: JsValue): NonEmptySeq[A] = json match {
     case JsArray(Vector(value, values @ _*)) => 
       (value.converTo[A], values.map(_.convertTo[A]))
  }

  override def write(xs: NonEmptySeq[A]): JsValue =
    JsArray(Foo.toSeq[A](xs).map(_.toJson): _*)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use spray's seq format to inherit already implemented functionality and place your own logic on top of that.

First call `implicitly[JsonFormat[Seq[A]]]` to get json formatter for `Seq[A]`. Writing `NonEmptySeq[A]` is trivial since you know how to write `Seq[A]` and how to convert `NonEmptySeq[A]` to `Seq[A]`.  When reading `NonEmptySeq[A]`, first read is as `Seq[A]` and then validate it contains at least one element. If it validates, you got a `NonEmptySeq[A]`, if it is not, give a DeserializationError.

```
class NonEmptySeqFormat[A : JsonFormat] extends JsonFormat[NonEmptySeq[A]] {

  // this is implemented by spray developers
  val seqFormat = implicitly[JsonFormat[Seq[A]]]

  // read json as Seq[A] then check if it contains at least 1 element
  def read(json: JsValue): NonEmptySeq[A] =
    seqFormat.read(json) match {
      case x +: xs => (x, xs)
      case e => deserializationError("There should be at least one element, but got " + e)
    }

  // convert NonEmptySeq to Seq and then write it as json
  def write(xs: NonEmptySeq[A]): JsValue =
    seqFormat.write(Foo.toSeq(xs))

}
```